# Word 2016 freezes when switching languages

Tags: microsoft-word, freeze

I have had this problem on and off and I haven't been able to find the reason. 
Word 2016 freezes when I change the language using custom defined short keys (Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2). More interesting that it won't freeze if I change the language from language bar (by selecting the language in notification area).

All I guess is that there is some wrong information in word files that cause this kind of freezing (might also be from conflicting shortcut keys).

Many people have this problem and Microsoft has not given any solution. The problem is mentioned in these questions:

[Q1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-word/word-2016-crashes-when-switching-language-input/9d4f550e-961d-4eeb-ae83-39f4086a03d6/?auth=1),  [Q2](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-word/word-2016-crashes-when-using-bengali-typing-input/d4ae549e-ea08-4b1b-aae7-cd334b251e84/),  [Q3](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-word/word-2016-365-crashes-at-language-switching/76fe3384-e693-45e2-9f2c-14cd072dd989)

Comment: *This guy lives in 2106*

Comment: Try this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/word-2016-365-crashes-at-language-switching/76fe3384-e693-45e2-9f2c-14cd072dd989?auth=1

Comment: That link does not contain a successful solution, I listed it myself in my question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see... Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and solved it.

There is the options menu for languages in MS Word settings  . 
It listed my one other language (Chinese) as Not Installed. 
I removed this language from the list (only from MS Office, not from the system) and it did the magic.

**Another** solution is to install additional language pack from here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Language-Accessory-Pack-for-Office-2016-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

then languages will be shown as installed and Word no longer crashes when you use keyboard shortcuts to switch between keyboards (Ctrl+1 | Ctrl+Shift+1 | etc..)

Comment: Might be the answer. I upgraded to 2019 (it still crashed) and I installed language packs for all the listed languages and I guess I did not have a crash since a few months ago.

Comment: Cool, glad to know that!

Answer (score 1):

If you set key combination to change a language like Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2 etc. then it conflicts with Word shortcuts to increase line spacing.

Go to File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Keyboard shortcuts (customize) -> All Commands -> select SpacePara1 & SpacePara2, select shortcuts and Remove them.

[check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXXSb.png)

Comment: are you sure that causes the freeze? I recall that I removed those shortcuts but still it would freeze...

Comment: you saved my day!